# Creating a Bitmap from a PictureBox Image

Tags: .net, image, bitmap, gdi+, bitmapdata

In a .NET application, I have images of different formats (such as `Format1bppIndexed`) stored in `PictureBoxes`. I can fetch them using the property `Image` of the boxes.

Then I need to convert them to the `Bitmap` class to access the internal data. (The `Image` class does not support `LockBits`, as `Bitmap` does.)

Now to transfer the `Image` to a `Bitmap`, you need the `Bitmap` constructor taking an `Image` argument. The trouble starts here: this constructor converts the image to the format `Format32bppRgb`, whatever the initial type, and there is no overload of the constructor that allows forcing the format.

Worse, when the format is `Format16bppGrayScale`, a `System.ArgumentException` is raised by the constructor.

But I want to access the raw data without intermediate conversions, including 16 bits images. Any workaround ?

---

After more investigation, I observe that the support for 16 bits images is really poor under .NET. In particular, you **cannot** display them with `DrawImage`.

Comment: _when the format is Format16bppGrayScale_ Does you mean you can display those in a PictureBox? How would you do that?

Comment: @TaW: the image can be loaded in the PictureBox. Presumably, the frameworks converts it then.

Answer (score 0):

Some details about your request are not compeletely clear to me, so I am taking some assumptions.

Simple solution might be to create a "*shadow object*" that supports what you need and let the `PictureBox` display processed result. Any operations you would perform on the `image` in `PictureBox` would, in reality, be applied to your shadow object.

But I'm not sure, if it can be applied to this particular scenario. It mostly depends on *why* you need to put pixels into memmory using `LockBits`. It may indicate you're gaining speed and with a shadow object you might be back to square one or worse.

Comment: Thank you for caring about my question. Since, I have understood that there is lack of support of 16 bits images in .NET, and I just have to live with that.

Comment: In fact I already have this shadow object (a bitmap), but I need to initialize it *from* the picture box, and this is where I am stuck. To process the image, Lockbits is a must.

Comment: Just out of my interest, why do you need to initialize it from `PictureBox`? I'm asking, because I often use graphics on a "shadow" bitmap, while to users it appears he works with `PictureBox.Image`. Typically with drag&drop schedules and such.

Comment: That's a customer's requirement. Non negotiable :-) (Actually the application code is not in my hands.)